# Future-proofing Mobile Applications

Tags: user-interface, mobile, cross-platform, bluetooth, compatibility

We're working on the next version of a tracking system. The previous incarnation used an LCD with a simple custom UI however as we've had usability problems and we've found development time-consuming, and as our display is going out of production, we're considering using a regular cellphone or PDA as the interface instead.

Our main worry is whether we can keep such a product on the market for five to ten years without having to continually keep porting and adapting the application to new devices. To make things somewhat easier we intend to bundle the phones with the system, though in an ideal world our (largely non-technical) users would be able to use their own.

So, what's our best bet? Are there a good platform-independent libraries we can count on being supported for a while? Or are we better of betting on a single platform at a time? Perhaps backward-compatibility is more likely to be maintained on a PDA? Truth be told I'm not even sure what language to bet on for the generic parts of the code.

I'm also a little anxious about the link to our hardware. Bluetooth SPP is attractive since it's particularly easy to use and there are plenty of ready-made modules available, but support on the phone side is far from universal.

Any pragmatic advice would be most welcome as I must admit to having no experience with mobile application development.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't control the entire production chain for hardware like Apple does for example, you have no chance on long term. Unless your product is really innovative and market wants it so much, or if you are playing on a market niche (healthcare for instance). My proposal would be to make a market study and check what your customer use as mobile devices first. You should choose one or two top platforms first, and gradually add new platforms if market asks. If you are in US probably iPhone, Android, RIM would be the top choices, in Europe I would have to choose between iPhone, Android, Symbian, Windows. It's the same like developing a website you start with two top browsers and gradually add support for minor ones.

About portable libraries I wouldn't bet on this. Instead I would design an architecture using abstraction layers. For example I would have Bluetooth abstraction layer that would expose functionalities to my Business Logic Layer; underneath I would have BlueZ if I deploy on Android/Linux, maybe GameKit for iPhone, MS stack or Widcomm for Windows and so on.

PDAs are dead, actually they've merged into smartphones and tablets, they were an evolutionary step. So forget them.

HTML5 is a good idea but is only the front layer, you must deal also business logic and lower layers.

Bluetooth SPP is good because it is common, and interoperable it's like the webservices for enterprise. Instead of giving an API that is platform dependent you could provide a set of custom AT commands, that can be used by anyone that can connect on Bluetooth to SPP.

Comment: Thank you. The phone will be used as a graphical interface, as our device needs to keep running without one present. As I mentioned earlier we'll be supplying specific phones with the product, so we won't be porting until we can no longer buy compatible phones. Our main fear is that unless we choose our technologies carefully we'll have to keep porting every other year and end up maintaining backward compatibility for the old devices. Where would you place your bet? Android is huge, Microsoft have made their fortune on compatibility, and Apple seem not to support SPP.

Comment: Android has a problem because it becoming more fragmented with each device, since every vendor makes it's own hardware and they arrive to situation when application are no longer compatible with certain platforms. But the huge advantage remain the great market share. Microsoft strategy on the other hand is set hardware requirements, so the platform is somehow consistent across different vendors, which is something good, but their market share still remain under 10%. Gartner says the Windows Phone will explode in the near future, but who knows?

Answer (score 0):

Cross platform sounds like HTML 5, CSS and Javascript, along with some javascript frameworks for mobile development like the ones listed [here](http://blog.frontendforce.com/2010/05/mobile-application-development-using-javascript/)

Comment: Considering the reference to "our hardware" and "Bluetooth SPP", I don't think this is an option...

Comment: That's an interesting alternative. We'd need to support for several platforms of course, otherwise we'd just be compounding our risk by relying on both the device and framework being supported in the future. PhoneGap apparently runs on quite a few and claims to support "native APIs", which presumably means that we can add our own little Bluetooth hook. I'm assuming these things run without internet access and look like regular applications?